# Get The number in a specific string

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regex expression for get the number in a string, for example:

```
(white space) Schema.PCK.Name14500 (line feed)
```

or

```
(white space) Schema.PCK.14500Name (line feed)
```

or

```
(white space) Schema.PCK.Dog14500Cat (line feed)
```

Thanks.

Comment: That work for one case and match all the string and no only the numbers.

Comment: If there is only one number can't you do string.select(x => x.isdigit)? (On phone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var input = "Schema.PCK.*14500*Name";
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"Schema\.PCK\.([a-zA-Z]*)(?<num>\d+)");
var match = pattern.Match(input);
string num = match.Groups["num"].Value;
```

Comment: Wow, I did not know you could name matchgroups in C#/.NET!

Comment: his input contains only a match of number so I don't think the pattern should match against other parts, just number is enough.

Comment: @KingKing I understand OP need to extract the number from his sample strings. if at all any numbers he would like to match I'll update my answer

Comment: @Cobra_Fast some of the Regex engines supports named groups. Obviously .net is one of them.

Comment: Only Match for the second case/example. Anyway, Thank you.

Comment: @user2740274 Updated my answer for matching all the three

Answer (score 0):

Just `(\d+)` should do unless you have multiple numbers.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying this:-

```
resultString = Regex.Match(subjectString, @"\d+").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, then what you need is the whole match:

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"(?<= Schema\.PCK\.)[0-9]+(?=[\n]*\n)");
```